# C language check

Tags: c, compiler-errors, helper

Can anybody check my code please?
i couldn't find the error or the misbehavior of my code.
Note that when i assign a value for x inside the program everything goes well, but if i want the user to assign a value for x, the program doesn't work properly.
And sorry for my bad english. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sorting( int array[], int x){
    for (int i = 0; i < x-1; i++) // The (x-1) is because we are starting at index zero!!
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < x-1; j++)
        {
            if (array[j]>array[j+1])
            {
                int temp;
                temp=array[j];
                array[j]=array[j+1];
                array[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
void printing(int array[],int x) {
    printf("\nThe sorting is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        printf("%d,\t",array[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int x;
    int array[x];

    printf("Enter the size of your array as a natural no:\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("Now enter %d nos to be arrange:\n" ,x);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a no:\n");
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    printf("The array of %d int no:\n",x);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        printf("%d,\t", array[i]);
    }
    
    sorting(array,x);
    printing(array,x);

    return 0;
}

//I tried to assign a value for x inside the program everything goes well, but if i want the user to assign a value for x, the program doesn't work properly.
```

Comment: What value do you think `x` will have when you declare `int array[x]`?

Comment: You should first read a **valid** integer for `x` and then declare your array.

Comment: declaring the array before you take it's size and creating the array will result in undefined behaviour

Comment: [How to declare variable-length arrays correctly?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283440)

Comment: Does your compiler tell something about using `x` without assigning a value first? Compiler warnings are a servcie for you. Don't waste it.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. It is now working correctly. I need to declare my variable from my user input before the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scan the `x` before array definition, otherwise `x` has undetermined value and you invoke ***U***ndefied ***B***ehaviour

```
int main(){
    int x;
    int array[x];

    printf("Enter the size of your array as a natural no:\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
```

=====>

```
int main(){
    size_t x;

    printf("Enter the size of your array as a natural no:\n");
    if(scanf("%zu",&x) != 1 {/* handle scanf error */}

    int array[x];
```